# CSV import into database, varying foreign key attributes at runtime

Tags: mysql, hibernate, csv

Schema:
[image]

- gehört zu = belongs to
- hat = has
- Wert = value

Person and Account records are written to databse. Now, i have to link both together. Best practice?

**Summary:**
As to the answers, the only way to do that, is to link Accounts with matching a person through special code. Hibernate isn't able to do that.

On the first glance, this seems to be an easy task, but let me explain you the situation:

I have data copies of CSV files from accounts and person. `Person - Account a related via a 1:n relationship.` I want to import these entities into a `mysql` database with the help of hibernate. The problem is that the foreign key relationships between Person and Account are only known at runtime. That means, i cannot just write:

```
   // …
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
   public Person getPerson() {
   return person;
   }
   // …
```

Account records are composed of different attribute fields, dependent from the sort of account (SAP accounts have different attributes than AD accounts for instance).
The connection between `ADSAccount` and Person is done via the attributes `ADSAccount.SAMAccountName` und `Person.CentralAccount`. For SAP accounts, the connecting attributes are `SAPAccount.accn`t and `Person.CentralSAPAccount`. That means, the connecting attributes vary from account type to account type. This said, i have a big problem. How can i tell hibernate at compile time how to connect Account and Person, that is, how shall i define the foreign key relationships?

**UPDATE:**
I do not need to have knowledge of the attribute fields at compile time. `Person` and `Account` are associated through a many-to-many relationship with an `Attribut` Entity. This way i can dynamically add attributes including values (stored in the join table) at runtime!

But the problem with wiring `Person` and `Account` still exists. The connecting attributes are only known at runtime and hibernate wants this information at compile time.

**UPDATE** (10:25 22.02.2014):
Roman has pointed it out: "Special handling will be needed during import as import code will need to find person_id based on business key of Account." This is exactly my actual problem i could need assistance for. The bruteforce approach would be to loop all accounts and to look for everyone of them for a matching person = "Amount of Accounts" (loaded into a List) x "Amount of Person" (a db hit for every person) operations. This caused a stackoverflow in my program.

How could this special handling look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to represent association in some generalized form. And generalization nature is that you want to have attributes names which are used to link object to be dynamic.

Hibernate does not support this. 
It seems to me that main source of your problem is that type of Account and field which should be used is known in runtime but this is easy to overcome by using surrogate key.
. If this is the case just base the association not on business key of `Account` but on surrogate key of `Person`. This is straightforward to express in hibernate mapping either using FK in account table or using separate table. This allows to add new types of Accounts without changing the model (if you need this otherwise just create abstract `Account` with subclass per account type).

Special handling will be needed during import as import code will need to find person_id based on business key of `Account`.

Comment: This would imply that i had to hardcode the corresponding attributes in my Account-Subclasses. There had to be knowledge about these a compile time. But, i aim for just starting the import routine, let it read an xml file containing the different accounts and foreign key relationships and connect the accounts and persons at runtime.

Comment: Regardless of import you need to hardcode the attributed names used for FK relationships if you want to use hibernate. Think how would you model (and map) your entities if you don't have any import.

Comment: I can map Person and Account using hibernate. Both entities have only two properties, an ID and a referencing property to the other entity. All other attributes a stored in a join table that connects both, person and account, with an attribut entity. The join table hold the property value. See: http://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/ "Mapping a many-to-many join table with extra column using JPA" for details. So, i do not need to have any knowledge about these two entities at compile time.

Comment: "is easy to overcome by using surrogate key. ." This is exactly what i do. "Special handling will be needed during import as import code will need to find person_id based on business key of Account." You hit the bull's eye. This is what im trying now and this is what causes stackoverflows in a regular basis (see post)